# Script to transfer data from one table to another table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named Lead and another table named Sheet. I want to transfer the data in the table sheet to Table Lead. Also, I want the first ID of the table sheet to become the last ID of the lead table and the new IDs of the lead table will be filled as it is inserted.
How to write the script in SQL Server.

How can I write a general script to do this for me?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Or if you're feeling lucky, use a _"blind"_ INSERT (which will probably fail and/or insert the wrong data into the wrong columns), but it's as simple as `INSERT INTO destinationTable SELECT * FROM sourceTable;`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to have an identity in your lead table, but prepopulate it with existing values.

Since you were kind enough not to provide any sample data or table definition, I'm going to wing it with some dummy tables:

```sql
create table Sheet (id INT, someOtherData VARCHAR(30))

create table Lead (id INT IDENTITY, someOtherData VARCHAR(30))

-- Some test data
INSERT INTO Sheet
VALUES  (1, 'Test1')
,   (2, 'Test2')
,   (3, 'Test3')

-- Now the actual insert...

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Lead ON

INSERT INTO Lead (
    id, someOtherData
)
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id DESC), someOtherData
FROM    Sheet

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Lead OFF

-- This fixes the current identity value
DBCC CHECKIDENT(Lead, RESEED);


-- As a test, add another Lead
INSERT INTO Lead (someOtherData)
SELECT  'TestTest'

SELECT  *
FROM    Lead
```

One thing I don't like with this solution is that you're losing the connection between the original Sheet and Lead data. I'm not sure why you want to "first ID of the table sheet to become the last ID of the lead table", but if you don't, you can just change ROW_NUMBER thing to "id".